# Put Pandas Data Frame to Existing Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to put data frame into existing Excel sheet. I have a Data Frame that I need to copy into specific Excel sheet to specific location in the sheet, to cell A2, so it will mirror(paste) the whole data frame. Starting from selected cell(like the the picture) and including cells below. In this way I do not have to assign values to specific cell one by one.

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=list('ABC')`

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not use csv? csv format is openable in excel. csv is open source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It worked for me** using `xlwings`. Keeping all data and style format.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

#create DF
df = pd.DataFrame([[7,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=list('ABC'))

#load workbook
app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book('doc.xlsx')  
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

#Update workbook at specified range
ws.range('A2').options(index=False).value = df

#Close workbook
wb.save()
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

[**Result**]

Data Frame is copied to specific *Excel* sheet `Sheet1` to specific location cell `A2`, without losing any information. In this example, the **chart** is updated automatically referencing `A2:C4`.

[image]

Comment: For some reasons this solution does not work for large pandas dataframe. I receive an error message that the process has timed out

Comment: Not sure if it's possible on Linux. IMO better to use `openpyxl` to avoid OS specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas allows you to write a dataframe to excel and specify the column and row number to start from.

So in your case, you can mention

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
         startcol=1, startrow=2)
```

The `sheet_name` needs to be updated accordingly

---

So you entire code could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fn = r'C:\YourFolder\doc.xlsx'
book = load_workbook(fn)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], columns=list('ABC'))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn, engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index=False,
             startcol=1, startrow=2)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I used your code, but got an attributeError: can't set attribute 'sheets'. What could be the problem?

Comment: this [github discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52483#issuecomment-1505103455) talks about this issue. There have been some deprecations. Unfortunately, I won't be able t verify this. Please refer to this and feel free to update the answer if required.

Answer (score 2):

## How to write data to an arbitrary location in an existing Excel workbook

[<kbd>openpyxl 3.0.10</kbd>](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)
[<kbd>pandas 1.5.1</kbd>](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Let's see this workflow:

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

# create a dummy data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': [*'abcd'],
    'two': [*'wxyz'],
})

# write data into a new file
file_name = 'test_openpyxl.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name)

# NOTE: stop here and see the data in Excel,
#       close the file before continuing

# create a writer with parameters mode and if_sheet_exists
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    path=file_name,
    engine='openpyxl',
    mode='a',                   # append data to the file
    if_sheet_exists='overlay'   # keep previous data on existing sheets
)

# update data and write changes to the file
df['two'] = df['two'].str.upper()
df.to_excel(
    writer,                    # use openpyxl writer
    sheet_name='Sheet1',       # to update data on the existing sheet
    columns=['two'],           # in this only columns
    header=False,              # with no headers
    index=False,               # and no index printed
    startrow=1,                # at this specific position 
    startcol=2,                # with rows and cols numbering from 0
)    

writer.close()                 # file is saved by default when close
```

This method is equally applicable in both Linux and Windows. Note that append mode is not supported with `xlsxwriter`, so we have to use `openpyxl` to update existing data. It's also best to avoid working with a file in both Python and Excel at the same time.

The key parameter is `if_sheet_exists` with `mode='a'`, which can be:

- `error` raise a ValueError.
- `new` Create a new sheet, with a name determined by the engine.
- `replace` Delete the contents of the sheet before writing to it.
- `overlay` Write contents to the existing sheet without removing the old

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if the given sheet exist and you can delete the existing sheet and add a new one.

```
import xlwings as xw
def df_to_excel_util(excel,sheet_to_dataFrame_map):

    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        wb = app.books.open(excel)            
        current_sheets = [sheet.name for sheet in wb.sheets]
        
        for sheet_name in sheet_to_dataFrame_map.keys():
            if sheet_name in  current_sheets:
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].delete()
            
            new_sheet = wb.sheets.add(after=wb.sheets.count)
            new_sheet.range('A1').value = sheet_to_dataFrame_map.get(sheet_name)
            new_sheet.name = sheet_name
        wb.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can to read the excel file with`pd.read_excel()`, copy the firs row to your DataFrame and save the DataFrame as excel file with a same name.

Comment: Thank you for this attempt. But this overwrites the whole file at all!!